# Issue looping on block containing a set of tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to check if a file named *deploy.db* exists. If it does not exist, I need to perform a set of tasks for which I am using a block.

Below is how I run the playbook

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml \
  -e Layer=APP \
  -e BASEPATH="/logs" \
  -e Filenames="file1,file2,file3"
```

Here is the playbook *test.yml*:

```yaml
---
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Construct 
     debug:
        msg: "Run"
   - block:
       - stat: path="{{ BASEPATH }}/deploy.db"
         register: currdb
       - file: path="{{ BASEPATH }}/deploy.db" state=touch recurse=no
         when: currdb.stat.exists == False
       - shell: "echo done>>{{ BASEPATH }}/deploy.db"
         when: currdb.stat.exists == False
     when: Layer == 'APP'
     with_items:
       - "{{ Filenames.split(',') }}"
```

I am getting the below error running the playbook:

> ```
> ERROR! 'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Block
>
> The error appears to be in '/app/test.yml': line 9, column 6, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
>    - block:
>      ^ here
> ```

After researching a bit, I understand that neither `with_items` nor `loop` is supported by a `block` and the solution is to include a tasks file.

I am, however, not sure how to get that to work. Can you suggest what tweaks I need in order to make my playbook work?

Considering I am on the latest version of Ansible, are there other solutions?

Comment: Support for this feature in Ansible was requested back in 2015, discussed at length, and finally closed in late 2017. See [feature request: looping over blocks #13262](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## TL;DR

> 'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Block

The error message says it all: you cannot loop over a block.

If you need to loop over a set of tasks, put them in a separate file and use [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html)

## Implementation (and some good practice...)

Below is an implementation based on your example illustrating the solution.

Since your question and code lacks some precision and since I pointed out some bad practices, please note that:

- I fixed the looped code to effectively use the `filenames` you loop on (I inferred it was supposed to be the `deploy.db` file). Note the use of `loop_control` to disambiguate the variable name in the included file (i.e. `db_filename`).
- I made the code idempotent as much as possible by using the ansible module `copy` in place of `shell` and dropped the `touch` phase.
- I transformed the var names to all lowercase and underscore separator.
- To make sure the copy task works on all occasion, I replaced the removed tasks with a single making sure the `basepath` dir exists.
- I added a `unique` filter after `filenames.split(',')` as well as a `trim` filter on each value to remove possible duplicates and eventual spaces added by error in the coma separated list.
- I used `not` keyword and `bool` filter (for extra security) rather than a bare compare to a boolean `False` value.

Here is the included file `create_db_each.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Check if file exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ basepath }}/{{ db_filename }}"
  register: currdb

- name: Create the file with "done" line if not present
  copy:
    content: "done"
    dest: "{{ basepath }}/{{ db_filename }}"
  when: not currdb.stat.exists | bool
```

used in the following `create_db.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- name: "Create my dbs"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure the base directory exists
      file:
        path: "{{ basepath }}"
        state: directory

    - name: load each db
      include_tasks: "create_db_each.yml"
      when: layer == 'APP'
      loop: "{{ filenames.split(',') | unique | map('trim') }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: db_filename
```

which gives

---

*notes:*

- *first run only, run it again on your side to witness it reports `OK` everywhere*
- *see the `filenames` parameter value to illustrate the use of `unique` and `trim`*

---

```
$ ansible-playbook -e basepath=/tmp/my/base/path -e "filenames='a.bla, b.toto, c , z.txt,a.bla'"  -e layer=APP create_db.yml

PLAY [Create my dbs] ************************************************

TASK [Make sure the base directory exists] **************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [load each db] *************************************************
included: /home/olcla/Sources/ZZ_tests/ansitests/create_db_each.yml for localhost => (item=a.bla)
included: /home/olcla/Sources/ZZ_tests/ansitests/create_db_each.yml for localhost => (item=b.toto)
included: /home/olcla/Sources/ZZ_tests/ansitests/create_db_each.yml for localhost => (item=c)
included: /home/olcla/Sources/ZZ_tests/ansitests/create_db_each.yml for localhost => (item=z.txt)

TASK [Check if file exists] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create the file with "done" line if not present] **************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Check if file exists] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create the file with "done" line if not present] **************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Check if file exists] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create the file with "done" line if not present] **************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Check if file exists] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create the file with "done" line if not present] **************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************
localhost: ok=13   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ tree /tmp/my/base/path/
/tmp/my/base/path/
├── a.bla
├── b.toto
├── c
└── z.txt

$ for f in /tmp/my/base/path/*; do cat $f; echo; done
done
done
done
done
```

Comment: I still don't understand this design choice it's meaningful to have a concept of block that you can loop on. being force to segregate portion of code in different files makes a town of clutter and confusion in the code base IMO. Thanks for the details explanation.

Comment: @Kiwy ansible is built on "good enough" design, they do not aim to provide an excellent tool, just good enough tool. This could be reasonable if the dev hours that can be put in a project are limited (which is more often the case than is not). If you browse issues in the repository you will see that many issues where there is a workaround are closed. This results in code full of kludges, but working nonetheless.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Agreed good enough is fine. Yet good enough when it comes to code makes for tons of clutter and poor maintainability. I love Ansible but as soon as a bit more complex task than just serial action is to happen, yes you can do it but the cost is insane. Ansible is maintained and backed by RedHat and IBM. It is no longer a small one person project. I find hard to swallow that basic development stuff like block and loops actually behave differently than anywhere else.